# Why doesn’t Squid proxy add X-Forwarded-For and Via headers as it should?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

According to the Squid proxy documentation the [Via](https://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/via/) and [Forwarded-For](https://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/forwarded_for/) Headers should be set per Default, but they aren't showing up in my configuration.

I installed a freshly instance of Squid and to keep it simple I only added `http_access allow all` to the config (not recommended, because insecure). But it's still not working.

I tried Squid version 3.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 and the squid version 5.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.
I tested with `http://httpbin.org/headers` in the browser (printed results are from version 3.5):

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", 
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-65d92b79-4f5d01607a3b091342c4e694"
  }
}
```

I also checked my public IP through `http://icanhazip.com` in the browser. This returned the IP of the proxy, so the connection works.

Are there any circumstances I need to consider?

Answer (score 1):

By running a simple Python Webserver, I could determine that the headers are indeed set accordingly.

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://<web-serverip>:<web-server-port>/
Host: <web-serverip>:<web-server-port>
Via: 1.1 <proxy_name> (squid/5.2)
X-Forwarded-For: <Client-IP>
Cache-Control: max-age=259200
Connection: keep-alive
```

It seems like the `/headers` endpoint of [http-bin](https://httpbin.org) has some sort of preprocessing that maybe strips some headers. So the issue was not with Squid itself, but rather with the mechanism used to verify its functionality.